# Should I delete my comments if I learned better?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've struggled with a given answer and left a comment. A small discussion arose. After reading more resources, I changed my opinion and now I think that my comments aren't useful anymore.

Should I remove my comments?

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31422376/846163

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the tag [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments)

> Comments are small addendum to each question or answer, intentionally limited in size and formatting. Comments are second-class citizens.

Comments are at best used to point-out issues with the post. They are a great way to get clarification if something is not clear. The best way to get that handled is by the OP to improve the post with an edit to resolve the issue addressed. After that the comments are obsolete and should be deleted, either by flagging or by self-moderation.

If you have expanded your knowledge and think it is relevant and unique enough to warrant an extra/new answer feel free to do so. In that answer you can elaborate how an earlier answer helped you to come up with your answer. That enables you to reduce any back-and-forth discussion to some relevant points.

If the outcome of what you misunderstood initially but became clear after an exchange of comments but doesn't warrant a new answer you could leave a final summarizing comment with a link to other resources if possible and then delete all your earlier comments. Ask the other participants to do the same or use your comment flags, which ever works best.

Comment: In my case I added another answer. Therefore I will to delete my comments.

Comment: @sschmeck note that if you don't `@` me, I don't know you've commented! I've deleted some of mine now, too.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, nice to meet you here. Thanks for your the advice. Next time I'll use the @.

Comment: @sschmeck: You can also flag the question or answer the comments are attached to using the "Needs moderator attention" flag and say which comments are no longer useful. Be as clear as possible, and leave your comments there so the mod has the full picture. Then they can clean everything up.

Answer (score 12):

Remember that [Obsolete is one of the reasons to flag a comment!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237980#237980)

> **obsolete** comments are those which served a purpose once upon a time but no longer: requests for clarification that've been addressed via edits, suggestions for improvement that were long ago heeded, etc. Don't worry about these if they're not displayed by default - if most readers don't see them, they're not causing any harm.

So, not only is it appropriate for you to delete your own comments if they are no longer relevant, it's actually appropriate for you to flag **the other person's comments as obsolete** after deleting your own if they are no longer relevant!

In my experience, you should rarely need to do this; I've found that many users who engage in comment clarification already delete their own comments if the person they were talking to has deleted theirs.

Comment: Do users engaged in comment conversation get notification when the earlier comment is deleted? Or do they just check the Q/A from time to time to know when their comments are not needed anymore?

Comment: @aff I don't know what other people do, but I usually check back on questions every so often for a little while after answering.

Comment: So, no notification or other magical things? ;(

Answer (score -6):

I think that even though you've changed your opinion, the comments still hold value. The discussion or path that you followed to get to a certain point is very relevant for future visitors.

Feel free to, for example, add an **updated** section to your question or answer for people who want to skip to the final solution directly.