# Should you delete comments about an error that was fixed?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Are comments considered historical record and should not be deleted even if they are no longer relevant (as in the case below), or are they simply temporary communication methods and should be removed when no longer needed?

I occasionally make comments about errors in answers, such as [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624071/autocomplete-in-bash-script/). If the author of the answer fixes the issue in question should I delete my comment about the error?

Comment: Comments are very much not a historical record. Delete it. If it's someone else's comment, you can even flag it with an "obsolete" reason for exactly the purpose you describe. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299356/215552

Comment: This is *exactly* why "obsolete" is a canned comment flag.

Comment: Follow up question: should you actively go back to all comments you have made and clean them up? Answer: that's entirely your own choice. The site is chock full of comments which have no purpose anymore, its not going to become unusable because your comments are there too ;)

Comment: On a related note, if you get into a comment discussion with an answer author that becomes obsolete it can be useful to ping the author saying something like "We should delete these comments now that they're obsolete". It's not a big deal, but it can look weird to future readers if you delete your half of the conversation, leaving the other person's comments without context. Of course, you _could_ flag their comments, but it's better if we can clean up our own messes rather than adding to the mods' workload.

Comment: I just want to point out that the bar for "fixed" is to make the answer better than the competing answers were at the time the edit was made.  If the correction is just regurgitating things described in other answers, the best fix is deletion of the wrong answer (and then the comments go with it).  We don't want to reward FGITW for leaving placeholder answers on topics they know nothing about themselves and just wait to take credit for everything the comments and other answers tell them is important.

Comment: What is FGITW short for?

Comment: Fastest Gun In The West

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, such comments should be deleted. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> ### When should comments be deleted?
>
> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or
>   answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You should
>   not expect them to be around forever: Once a clarification has been
>   made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the
>   issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion.
>   In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to
>   the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they
>   can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.