# Should you comment after you edit your question in response to comments?

Tags: support, edits, comments

A common scenario is that someone posts an unclear question, and users leave comments and ask for clarity or details. If you edit your question, it is "bumped" to the active questions, but the commenters don't get a notification. You can comment your own question along the lines: "I have edited the question to make it clearer.", and tag them, but I'm uncertain if this falls under [relevant but **minor or transient information**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)?

Should you comment your question, and notify those that left a comment that you have made an edit? Or should you leave it up to the system that has put your question back to the active questions?

This is probably another discussion entirely, but if we should not comment our question after making an edit, should we flag comments that do for deletion? If the edit is made, then the comments asking for clarification should be deleted ([since those comments are now obsolete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335532/should-you-delete-comments-about-an-error-that-was-fixed)), and thus making the "I have now edited the question" comment obsolete as well.

Comment: I'm always happy if I get such a notification! I think it is a nice service from you to the people trying to help you. (to not clutter the site, you can delete your comment again once you can safely assume the recipient has seen it, e.g. after they answered your question or left some follow up comment)

Comment: FWIW, some people who leave improvement request comments follow the post, so they get notified when an edit occurs.

Comment: It should not, however, be *assumed* that someone who asked for clarification will be following your question; I personally don't follow unless I have a very keen interest in the question. (If I did follow every question I ask for people to clarify on, my Following list would be *huge* too! :'( )

Comment: what would be nice would be a popup ""do you want to follow this post" whenever I leave a comment with a magic MRE comment

Comment: " If you edit your question, it is "bumped" to the active questions, but the commenters don't get a notification." - This is potentially false. These users can follow the question and be notified of changes. I don't personally follow posts, since I would get dozens of notifications a day, but that's just me.

Answer (score 17):

There is nothing wrong with notifying other apparently interested users of improvements to the question, particularly if the edits where made in response to their comments.

That being said, it's perfectly fine to flag all those comments as "no longer needed" when you encounter them (both the original comments that prompted the edit, and the ones replying to those).

That it is **not** **wrong** to leave a comment does not mean it shouldn't be flagged/deleted at some point.

In that vein it's also fine if you delete your own comments after a while, or after you have evidence that the other party has read them. Those are no longer needed, no need to wait for a flag.

As an aside, it's better to leave more meaningful comments than *"updated my question @whoever"*. More useful to post something like *"I've added the relevant configuration, @foobar. Does this cover it?"*, etc.

Answer (score -3):

If you know that the user who left the comment wanted to be informed, then you can ping them. But if the user really wanted to be pinged they would have followed the post. You can't see who follows the post, so pinging people who ask for clarification is generally considered noise.

If the edit you made addressed a particular comment, then flag that comment as no longer needed. A moderator will delete it.

Comment: The assumption here feels too strong. I, for one, do not have the habit of following posts, and expect that people will ping me if they want to reply to something I said in a comment. Larnu makes a similar point [in a comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412831/should-you-comment-after-you-edit-your-question-in-response-to-comments#comment877618_412831) ("I personally don't follow unless I have a very keen interest in the question").